# C# how to send email?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using C#.NET 4.0 and would like to send an email to an address with a subject and a body, the body will contain some information from a few text-boxes in my application.

I have little to no experience with sending emails in C#, so any help here would be appreciated. All I know is that you have to use the System.Net.Mail namespace. I tried this code but it gave an "Failure sending Mail" exception.

```
        new SmtpClient("smtp.server.com", 25).Send("test@hotmail.com",
                                       "test@gmail.com",
                                       "subject",
                                       "body");
```

What is wrong with the above code? Furthermore, is there any better way to send the email?

Comment: There are 3422352232341 sample about Sending Mail in ASP.NET on Stackoverflow and Internet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked with three well known ISP’s to host my client’s websites.  All three ISP's instructed me to use “localhost” as the smtp server name.

Comment: localhost will only work if the mailserver in on your own server. If you are using gmail (or e.g. Planet internet) this is not the case. You really need the mailserver of your email provider (e.g. mail.planet.nl)

Answer (score 17):

Probably your authentication (credentials) or servername/port is not correct.

Try this:

```
        MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();
        mailMsg.To.Add("test@hotmail.com");
                    // From
        MailAddress mailAddress = new MailAddress("you@hotmail.com");
        mailMsg.From = mailAddress;

        // Subject and Body
        mailMsg.Subject = "subject";
        mailMsg.Body = "body";

        // Init SmtpClient and send on port 587 in my case. (Usual=port25)
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("mailserver", 587);
        System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = 
           new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;

        smtpClient.Send(mailMsg);
```

Answer (score 8):

you cannot leave this string:

> smtp.server.com

you should have there the name of your smtp server, usually something like mail.yourcompanyname.com or smtp.yourcompanyname.com

Comment: Um.. I have no idea what an SMTP server is. How am I supposed to figure out what mine is, and what port I actually have?

Comment: if you are inside a company ask the network administrator if you are in private office check the parameters of your internet provider, if you find nothing create a gmail account and check in gmail website how to enable, use and configure smpt and pop3 with GMail.

Comment: I already figured it out. Thanks for the help anyway, though.

Answer (score 2):

Is smtp.server.com really an SMTP server? You need to replace that with a real one. Your ISP probably provides you one, but it will likely only relay for emails originating from an address that your ISP owns.

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question asked here.