# Email send service for .NET

Tags: .net, email

I'm looking for some email send service for .NET that:

- would be accessible via web service (client app can order the service to send an email to a given recepient)
- would store sent emails (administrator or business person can always view what emails have been sent recently)

Do you know of any tool of that type?

Comment: what code language are you using?

Comment: I think it should be language agnostic. As I mentioned it should be accessible via web service.

Comment: Sounds like you need a .NET IMAP client for e.g. GMail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smtp clients can be invoked directly in code [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028728/c-how-to-send-email)  so you could have a wcf webservice that takes in a parameter of the email address and send the email out in code through whatever smtp server your using.  At the same time you can log whats happened either to log files or a database.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to write an enterprise-class solution, I will suggest some options:

1. JMS-based solution:
   Create a publisher topic since topics can have multiple publishers. Bridge this topic to a queue. This will be the listener queue for the email-send service. Your email send service can be in any language. Almost all programming languages can connect to JMS-based messaging software (Apache ActiveMQ). Your subscribing apps should send an XML message to the topic. The listener email-send process will read and send the email. You can write truly async pattern using this.
2. If you don't want JMS, then you can do the same thing with database persistence. Persist all email requests to a DB. The email-send service will poll this database and send the email.
3. A least recommended approach is to write a WCF service.

Lastly, I assume that you already know how to write an SMTP wrapper using .Net or any other language.

Answer (score 0):

GMail | HotMail | YahooMail | .....Mail | Microsoft Exchange

Client can access the Web Service via the standard SMTP interface. .Net has a nice library for that. OK, its not a HTTP Web Service, but its a TCP/IP Web Service.

It stores your in & outgoing email.

Comment: I'm seeking some more enterprise oriented solution. Let's call it a central email send service. Almost each of our applications (and there are lots of them) need to send some emails to our client. We think it would be good if we had central service that'd do the job.

Comment: Ah, but that was not in your question. What about Microsoft Exchange?

Answer (score 0):

If you can create an HTTP POST request using JSON, [PostageApp](http://postageapp.com) can easily handle what you are looking for.

You can create the web interface that would talk with our API whenever a client wishes to send out an email, and you have an archive of recently sent messages on our backend. Now, if you're looking for just an email client to send and receive, that might be something else completely.

Let me know if you have any questions.

(**Disclosure:** I am the Product Manager of PostageApp.)