# Extracting data from infopath forms

Tags: infopath, infopath-2007

I would like to extract the fields in an infopath form to be sent plaintext in an email. The default option in infopath is to either include the entire formatted form in the email, or have it attached. I would just like the extracted data to be included in the body of the email.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign fields or functions to several e-mail properties, however it's very limited. See the following screenshot:
[image]

I don't think you will get any further without custom code. You could create a button action which takes the values from the fields you need and sends an e-mail programmatically. Here are some links that might help you -

[C# how to send email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028728/c-how-to-send-email)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb509311(v=office.12).aspx