# .NET SMTP Client - Client does not have permissions to send as this sender

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, smtp

I'm getting strange occurance on our servers when I am trying to send an email using SmtpClient class via an ASP MVC3 project. This is the code I am using.

```
try
{
    var client = new SmtpClient("MailServer");
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

    MailMessage message = new MailMessage("me@mydomain.com", "friend@mydomain.com", "Test Message", "Test Body");
    client.Send(message);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Do Nothing
}
```

I have deployed on three environments; on Windows 7 (using VS 2010 IIS) it sends the email fine, on the Windows 2003 IIS6 machine it sends the email fine, finally on the Windows 2008 R2 II7 server I get the following error:

```
Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender using username
```

Can anybody advise on what may be causing this. I have noticed that when I view `User.Identity.Name`, this is returning an empty string.

Comment: Strange you get an empty identity name, try to disable anonymous account and have the web app to impersonate a certain user and see if it works.

Comment: Hi, if I replace with the following: client.UseDefaultCredentials = false; client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myAccount", "myPassword", "myDomain");

The email sends through fine.

Comment: ok, but I would not put pwd and username in the code, use at minimum web config!

Comment: you might want to check out this question and answe as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028728/c-how-to-send-email

Comment: Hi, I have looked at that question, but I'm not sure it is related. Btw, the pwd/username in the code was only for test ;)

Comment: What is your reason for ignoring the exception?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is likely that the mail server does not support sending anonymous emails and will require credentials to be specified which are registered on the mail server.

You can specify the credentials like so:

```
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, but I am able to use the mail server without providing network credentials when I am on either my dev machine or one of our other servers. It is only on the Win2008 server I am having a problem.

Comment: @StrictlySocial - Is it possible that the configured account used for the application pool identity lacks sufficient privileges?

Comment: At the moment it is set to ApplicationPoolIdentity - I must admit when it gets to this level in IIS, I am lost

Comment: @StrictlySocial - You will either need to specify an account for the application pool (ApplicationPoolIdentity) which has the necessary permissions to send emails using the mail server, or configure your mail server to allow sending of emails from the web server to the mail server in its current state.

Comment: OK, I have changed the app pool to use my login details, and it works! (although obviously this isn't a resolution). I've also tried running as NetworkService and this fails as before.

Comment: @StrictlySocial - Your account is probably a domain account where as the NetworkService and the ApplicationPoolIdentity accounts are not. You can either create a restricted domain account to run the application pool as or I'm sure it is possible to configure your SMTP server to allow emails to be sent unauthenticated from your web server based on its IP address.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, although I've not got it working as yet, I think I am closer. I'll take your advice on allowing anonymous by IP address - will take ages to get the change authorised though :)

Answer (score 8):

If you are using an exchange server and the logon account and sender email are different you will got the error "does not have permissions to send...". This is because of the account permissions. You must grant "send as" permission to the logon account.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. Looks like here's an article on how to grant the permission - http://tom.603global.com/KB/a8/how-to-grant-send-as-permissions-one-account-ms-exchange.aspx. Note, that you need to hace access to the AD and the mail server to do that, which is not always available.

Answer (score 6):

I solve this problem removing authentication credentials from web.config

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="SystemAdmin@domain.do">
    <!--network host="EXCH-SERVER" port="25" userName="userName" password="password" defaultCredentials="false" /-->
    <network host="EXCH-SERVER" port="25" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have try everything and it is still failing, one possibility is that the server accept only anonymous user. If you try to connect with credentials:

- `defaultCredentials="true"`
- `defaultCredentials="false" userName="foo" password="false"`

Then the server WILL return the error `.NET SMTP Client - Client does not have permissions to send as this sender`.

That's weird, but as a last resort, just try the simple:

- **`defaultCredentials="false"`**

Answer (score 1):

For me it was using different credentials -

In network credentials I was using -

```
new NetworkCredential(smtpUser, smtpPassword)
```

and in fromAddress

```
 var fromAddress = new MailAddress("anotheruser@gmail.com", string.Empty);
```

Where when sending email where fromAddress is different than actual network credentials will lead this issue.
See below -

```
 using (var message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
                {
                    Subject = Keys.MailSubject,
                    Body = body,
                    IsBodyHtml = true
                })
                {
                    smtp.Send(message);

                }
```

The simple fix is to keep both the mails same as network credentials's one.

Comment: I have the same issue. Authentication fails as the from address is different than the network credentials. Is there a way around this ? Please guide.

Comment: Exactly the same issue. Thanks for this. Surprised there is no fix mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

What does User.Identity.IsAuthenticated return, if it returns false that is your problem.  You are trying to send mail as an unauthenticated user.

Comment: Hi, it returns false. How would I go about returning true? As far as I am aware Windows authentication is enabled. Within the web.config I have the following <authentication mode="Windows" />

Comment: You need to also disable anonymous authentication.  I usually do this at IIS level through the IIS management GUI rather than in the web.config.  Also are you that in this case User.Identity.Name is an empty string, i would expect it to be null.

Comment: Within the IIS7 GUI, I have disabled Anonymouse Authentication, ASP.NET Impersonation, and Forms Authentication. Only Windows Authentication is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue - the credentials from ASP.Net were never going to be something that could send e-mail in my environment.  So I figured out this path through the mess (which also includes the possibility that NTLM doesn't always work right and that I was putting the mail configuration info in web.config):

```
System.Net.Configuration.SmtpSection section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp") as System.Net.Configuration.SmtpSection;

// set up SMTP client
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
System.Net.CredentialCache myCache = new System.Net.CredentialCache();
NetworkCredential myCred = new NetworkCredential(section.Network.UserName, section.Network.Password);
string host = section.Network.Host;
int port = section.Network.Port;

// do this because NTLM doesn't work in all environments....
if (myCred != null)
{
    myCache.Add(host, port, "Digest", myCred);
    myCache.Add(host, port, "Basic", myCred);
    myCache.Add(host, port, "Digest-MD5", myCred);
    myCache.Add(host, port, "Digest MD5", myCred);
    myCache.Add(host, port, "Plain", myCred);
    myCache.Add(host, port, "Cram-MD5", myCred);
    myCache.Add(host, port, "Cram MD5", myCred);
    myCache.Add(host, port, "Login", myCred);

    //myCache.Add(host, port, "NTLM", myCred);
}
smtp.Credentials = myCache;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
//smtp.EnableSsl = true;
```

Depending on your configuration, you might need to uncomment the last line.

Answer (score 0):

One thing worked for me using Visual studio 2013 running packages.
i removed the 'Use Windows Authentication' tag in the SMTP Connection Manager Editor.