# Send Email using windows credentials of the application users

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am working on an application which sends email has one of the component that sends an email using the windows credentials of user.

```
string SMTP = "smtp.corp.com";
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(Sender, Recipient, Subject, Body);
SmtpClient smtpclient = new SmtpClient(SMTP, 25);
smtpclient.EnableSsl = false;
smtpclient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s,X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
smtpclient.Send(msg);
```

this code works fine on local machine but after deployment on the server it is giving error

```
Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender
```

since the sender in this case is:

`string Sender = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name+"@corp.com";`

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET SMTP Client - Client does not have permissions to send as this sender](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269174/net-smtp-client-client-does-not-have-permissions-to-send-as-this-sender)

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269174/net-smtp-client-client-does-not-have-permissions-to-send-as-this-sender

Answer (score 1):

At your local machine, your application run as administrator so have full permissions to send email. So it works at your local machine

But at the server, if your application doesn't run as administrator, it will not have permissions to send email. So it doesn't work at your server.

So the solution is, give your application the permission.

More detailed information please see this link: 
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/e763de97-88a1-494d-9841-4f3a466b5604/exchange-550-571-client-does-not-have-permissions-to-send-as-this-sender

Answer (score 0):

Due to insufficient access right you are getting this error in that case you have to provide them in first place.

Either you have changes like

```
smtpclient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpclient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

or Make changes in Web.Config like

```
 <mailSettings>
 <smtp from="SystemAdmin@domain.do">
  <!--network host="EXCH-SERVER" port="25" userName="userName" password="password"         
  defaultCredentials="false" /-->                                 
 <network host="EXCH-SERVER" port="25" />
 </smtp>
 </mailSettings>
```

Please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269174/net-smtp-client-client-does-not-have-permissions-to-send-as-this-sender)

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

> > after deployment on the server

Which windows users is it running as on the server? If this is ASP.Net running inside IIS, then it is using whatever identity you've set up in the application pool.... which is?