# Getting "Failure Sending Mail" exception while sending mail from Windows application

Tags: c#-4.0, smtp, windows

I am trying to send mail from my C# Windows application Localhost. While sending mail it's getting exception message "Failure sending Mail".

at `smtpClient.Send(message);` line. What is the issue?

```
           SmtpSection smtpSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp") as SmtpSection;

        StringBuilder bodyMessage = new StringBuilder();
        bodyMessage.Append("Error Importing the Asset XML File.");

        try
        {

            MailAddress to = new MailAddress("iramasani@gmail.com");
            MailAddress from = new MailAddress(smtpSection.From);
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
            message.Subject = "Error importing the Asset XML File.";
            message.Body = bodyMessage.ToString();                

            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(smtpSection.Network.Host, smtpSection.Network.Port);

            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtpClient.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogError("Error Sending mail "+ ex.Message);                
        }
    }
```

In the `app.config`:

```
<configuration>
     <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp from="admin@alticore.com">                
                <network host="localhost" port="25" defaultCredentials="true" />
            </smtp>              
        </mailSettings>        
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Which line of code produces the exception?

Comment: smtpClient.Send(message);

Comment: Are the mail server and your application running on the same machine? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028728/c-sharp-how-to-send-email) is a similar discussion.

Comment: Does that exception have any additional info in the `.InnerException` property (possibly nested, several levels down)? ?

Comment: Have you tried typing in the exact credentials instead of using the `defaultCredentials` property?

Comment: I am trying to send mail from Localhost not from any other servers(Like gmail).

Comment: Please answer marc_s's and my question ;-)

Comment: No I am not tried exact credentials.